# Redirect in result of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring

I created a login filter for my spring boot app:

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url, "POST"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        CustomUserDetails creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                req.getInputStream(), CustomUserDetails.class);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

The `WebSecurityConfiguration` :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("auth_code").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
        // We filter the api/signup requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTSignupFilter("/signup", authenticationManager(),
                    accountRepository, passwordEncoder),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in
        // header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I want to redirect to `/home` if the login was successful. How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `JWTLoginFilter` constructor:

```
setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/home"));
```